# border radius issue in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a rounded corner menu using css. It displays correctly in all browsers, including IE, but the mouse over color is not displaying in IE. I have used one script, corners.js, for the rounded corners. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: I should be yes...but you need to add some code, otherwise we cannot help.

Comment: can you put working code here or jsfiddle.net

Comment: Please refer the following location. http://jsfiddle.net/NFrGE/

Comment: It works [perfect](http://jsfiddle.net/NFrGE/1/).

Comment: IE7, IE8 ==> Menu link color displayed. Background color and background image are not working. Mouse Over Background color is missing when i put this css (-moz-border-radius:5px; -webkit-border-radius:5px;). When i remove it, background-color is displaying. Please guide me.

Answer (score -1):

For ie you must include Doctype otherwise mouse over property don't work

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```